# missing partial modern on declaration

Tags: c#

how can i correct the error im getting when i try to run my program,i found this program on the net and it seems it was compiled in visual c# 2005 and im using visual c# 2010
im getting this two errors before compiling

> Error 2   Ambiguity between 'RecursiveSearchCS.Form1.components' and
>   'RecursiveSearchCS.Form1.components'  C:\Users\jacr\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs    46  21  WindowsFormsApplication1
>
> Error 1   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties: 'RecursiveSearchCS.Form1.InitializeComponent()' and
>   'RecursiveSearchCS.Form1.InitializeComponent()'   C:\Users\jacr\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs
>
> 32    13  WindowsFormsApplication1

and when i try to compile it with errors im getting this

> Error 1   Missing partial modifier on declaration of type
>   'RecursiveSearchCS.Form1'; another partial declaration of this type
>   exists    C:\Users\jacr\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1t\Form1.cs   14  18  WindowsFormsApplication1t

what exactly am i supposed to do??my program searches files text files in a directory but it seems i getting this error ...this is the code on the `form1.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace RecursiveSearchCS
{
    public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        internal System.Windows.Forms.Button btnSearch;
        internal System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtFile;
        internal System.Windows.Forms.Label lblFile;
        internal System.Windows.Forms.Label lblDirectory;
        internal System.Windows.Forms.ListBox lstFilesFound;
        internal System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cboDirectory;
        private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (components != null)
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.btnSearch = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.txtFile = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.lblFile = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.lblDirectory = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.lstFilesFound = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
            this.cboDirectory = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();

            this.btnSearch.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(608, 248);
            this.btnSearch.Name = "btnSearch";
            this.btnSearch.TabIndex = 0;
            this.btnSearch.Text = "Search";
            this.btnSearch.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnSearch_Click);

            this.txtFile.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 40);
            this.txtFile.Name = "txtFile";
            this.txtFile.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 20);
            this.txtFile.TabIndex = 4;
            this.txtFile.Text = "*.dll";

            this.lblFile.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 16);
            this.lblFile.Name = "lblFile";
            this.lblFile.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(144, 16);
            this.lblFile.TabIndex = 5;
            this.lblFile.Text = "Search for files containing:";

            this.lblDirectory.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 96);
            this.lblDirectory.Name = "lblDirectory";
            this.lblDirectory.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 23);
            this.lblDirectory.TabIndex = 3;
            this.lblDirectory.Text = "Look In:";
            // 
            // lstFilesFound
            // 
            this.lstFilesFound.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(152, 8);
            this.lstFilesFound.Name = "lstFilesFound";
            this.lstFilesFound.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(528, 225);
            this.lstFilesFound.TabIndex = 1;

            this.cboDirectory.DropDownWidth = 112;
            this.cboDirectory.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 128);
            this.cboDirectory.Name = "cboDirectory";
            this.cboDirectory.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 21);
            this.cboDirectory.TabIndex = 2;
            this.cboDirectory.Text = "ComboBox1";

            this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 13);
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(688, 277);
            this.Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[] {

            this.btnSearch,
            this.txtFile,
            this.lblFile,
            this.lblDirectory,
            this.lstFilesFound,
            this.cboDirectory});

            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
        #endregion

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            lstFilesFound.Items.Clear();
            txtFile.Enabled = false;
            cboDirectory.Enabled = false;
            btnSearch.Text = "Searching...";
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            Application.DoEvents();
            DirSearch(cboDirectory.Text);
            btnSearch.Text = "Search";
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            txtFile.Enabled = true;
            cboDirectory.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            cboDirectory.Items.Clear();
            foreach (string s in Directory.GetLogicalDrives())
            {
                cboDirectory.Items.Add(s);
            }
            cboDirectory.Text = "C:\\";
        }

        void DirSearch(string sDir)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
                {
                    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, txtFile.Text))
                    {
                        lstFilesFound.Items.Add(f);
                    }
                    DirSearch(d);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception excpt)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you've given actually compiles perfectly well.

Looking at the errors, however, it seems you've got two copies:

```
C:\Users\jacr\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs

C:\Users\jacr\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1t\Form1.cs
```

Note the "t" at the end of the second directory name.

Get rid of one of these copies, and it should be fine. (You should be able to remove it in Visual Studio - I suspect you can see both `Form1.cs` files...)

Comment: i did get ride of it and now this error is coming up....Error 1 The type 'RecursiveSearchCS.Form1' already contains a definition for 'components' C:\Users\jacr\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 25 49 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: @hanna: Well we can't tell what line that's on, or what's going on in your project, to be honest. I suggest you start again from scratch. As I say, I've just compiled the code and it was fine. It sounds like you may have done something strange when creating the project or copying the file.

Comment: i opened a new project went to the solution explorer and clicked on form1.cs then pasted my code on the view code .....but im still getting these errors,how are you compiling it??

Comment: @hanna: I just saved the code into a file and ran `csc Test.cs`. The problem is probably that you're putting it into existing code where there's already a `Form1.Designer.cs`. Start again, and this time just copy the file into place and use "Add existing item" to add the class. I'm afraid it's a pain to walk you through it all here, but basically you don't want *any* of the normal Visual Studio-provided stuff. Start a new project, remove *all* the source files that it starts you off with, and just add the file as it is, not via "Add new form".

Answer (score 1):

Extend your `class` declaration with `partial` keyword:

```
public partial class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`partial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keyword like;

```
public partial class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

**EDIT**: It looks like you have two copies of this project;

> C:\Users\jacr\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs

and

> C:\Users\jacr\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1t\Form1.cs

Just get rid of one of this projects because you asking them at in the same question. Probably this is the reason.

Comment: @hanna: "its not working" is *never* enough information. Please give more details.

Comment: its showing there is an error on this code public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

Comment: @Habib Error 3 Ambiguity between 'RecursiveSearchCS.Form1.components' and 'RecursiveSearchCS.Form1.components' C:\Users\jacr\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 46 21 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: @SonerGönül i removed the other copy and im now getting this...Error 1 The type 'RecursiveSearchCS.Form1' already contains a definition for 'components' C:\Users\jacr\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 25 49 WindowsFormsApplication1

Answer (score 1):

Well as most already told you, you need the `partial`-keyword in your class declaration.

```
public partial class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

When you are working with Windows Forms, Visal Studio will split your form into several files (MyForm.cs for your code and MyForm.Designer.cs for autogenerated code for your UI elements and sometimes a resource-file to go with that). Since the class is split over several files, the `partial`-keyword is needed to tell the compiler to keep looking for more files before finalizing this class.

More info on the `partial`-keyword can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx